# Missing Navigation's or Back Button's Title When Push ViewControllers in Succession

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I have a problem on `UINavigationController` when pushing view controllers in succession.

For information, I use XCode 7.0, build targeting iOS 8, and the app running on Simulator 9.0.

Here's the view when user manually tap the tableview's cell:

[image: User manually push the controller by tapping on tableview's cell]

As shown on the above screenshots, the navigation's and back button's title were rendered normally.

But when I did this programmatically, like this (`stack` is array of `UIViewController`):

```
for controller in stack {
    self.mainNavController.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
}
```

or using delay on 0.0 second like this:

```
for controller in stack {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64((0.0 * Float(NSEC_PER_SEC)))), dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.mainNavController.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
    })
}
```

It will show the final result like this (left is w/o delay, right is w/ delay):

[image]

Notice the missing navigation title on the left screenshot (w/o delay) and missing back button title on the right screenshot (w/ delay).

This issue has confuse me for days. Any idea of why this is happening? Does anyone know how to fix this? Or at least, work around this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share the code where you init and add the bar button item?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this ? Still going iOS 13.3

Comment: Nope. Still didn't find a fix. Just a work around. In the end, I override the back button with my own bar button item, similar to the accepted answer below.

Comment: Actually thinking more about this I believe this could be expected behaviour. If  you open your second view controller manually you will have already initialized and shown on screen your first view controller and so its navigation would have been set. Then when the second vc is pushed, the navigation controller will use the first vc's navigation item to show the back button. If you do it programatically though, the first vc is not initialized and there is no navigation item for the nav controller to get the back title from.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be pushing view controllers with a loop given there is a UINavigationController function `setViewControllers:animated`

Comment: Yeah. I agree. I think your solution should be more appropriate to handle this task. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I still don't understand why there is no "Back" title next to the arrow. Seems like this happens sometimes and sometimes not. Bloody UIKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done in the past. You might find it helpful:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let myBackButton = UIBarButtonItem()
    myBackButton.title = "This is my back button"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = myBackButton
}
```

Comment: Well ... Although your answer didn't solve the issue, but you give me a hint so I remove the back button caption altogether (leaving only '<' icon).

I still don't know whether this an OS level issue or not though.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the intermediate view controllers are not being told to load so it isn't able to load things properly like the correct messaging for the back button. For any intermediate viewControllers, call loadViewIfNeeded() and then the upper view controllers can get all the required info from them.